# UITableView does not respond to scrolling the first time it's loaded

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have found that the first time a UITableView loads, it does not respond to scrolling touches -- if it does not have more rows than fit on the screen.  If I close the view, then reopen the same object -- it will now respond to touches -- even though it contains the same number of rows.

I am not doing anything more than responding to the UITableViewDataSource methods for the number of rows, and generating the rows themselves.  I am reloading the table every time the view appears.

Can anyone explain such behavior?

---

I am creating the cells like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *tableId = @"NewIndexTableId";
  Note *note = [notes objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableId];

  if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableId] autorelease];

  cell.textLabel.text = note.text;
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = [note changedDelta]; 
  cell.accessoryView = multipleAccounts ? [note.account imageView] : nil;

  return cell;  
}
```

Comment: Assuming you have an Interface Builder (`xib`) file that contains your `UITableView`, what settings did you enable in Interface Builder for that view?

Comment: Just the default settings with the delegate and datasources bound to the file's owner.

Comment: How are you creating the cells?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem by making sure there are always at least 10 rows in the table -- creating dummy rows when there are less than 10 real rows.  This solved the glitch.

Answer (score 19):

I had same problem. Bounce Scroll was enabled in IB, but still no love.
I had to set it in the code ( in viewDidLoad ) like so...

```
self.myTableView.bounces = YES;
```

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: and if that fails do this...
[self.tableView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];

Answer (score 0):

What does your xib file look like?  Do you have any views other than the UITableView?

Early on when I was learning iPhone programming, I somehow ended up with two UITableViews in my xib file - the table displayed properly, but was showing subtle problems.