# UITableView does not bounce/scroll after UISearchBar is added to view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView` filled with rows of data. There are only 3 or 4 rows of data which do not reach the bottom of the screen, but the table still bounces vertically as expected when swiping up and down. After adding a `UISearchBar` to the top row/header of the `UITableView` in Interface Builder, the table no longer bounces initially. However, after navigating to a different view and returning to the same view, the table once again bounces. Why does the `UITableView` not bounce when the view is initially loaded, and how do I make it so that it does bounce?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [table reloadData];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    [table reloadData];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    ...
    self.table = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Comment: Is the behaviour that you are after that it does scroll bounce or that it doesn't scroll bounce?

Comment: I would like it to scroll bounce.

Comment: Have you checked the `Always Bounce Vertically` property in the Scroll View properties of your `UITableView` in IB? (or programatically: the property `alwaysBounceVertical `)

Comment: Yes, that is set in IB. I have not tried setting it programatically, but why would it not bounce initially and then bounce when navigating back to the view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by implementing the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449261/uitableview-does-not-respond-to-scrolling-the-first-time-its-loaded).

The key was to add `self.tableView.bounces = YES` in the `viewDidLoad` method.