# UITableview Not scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using following code in `cellForRowAtIndex` method, but the `tableview` is not scrolling?

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;        

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"...%@...", hit.neighboringText];

return cell;
```

Comment: how many rows are there?

Comment: can you post more code because method you have mentioned takes cares of creating cell not scrolling

Comment: The UITableView should be scrollable (at least bouncable) by default. Make sure you are not changing its contentSize or userInteractionEnabled properties elsewhere and check its properties on IB (see Dharmbir's solution).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this this will clear your problem

```
self.myTableView.bounces = YES;
```

more info [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449261/uitableview-does-not-respond-to-scrolling-the-first-time-its-loaded)

Answer (score 11):

See your `xib` and make these thing checked.See in the below image

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks For this simple solution Bounce Vertically is working for me ! +1

Answer (score 3):

```
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
```

This should solve the problem!!

Comment: Hey - thanks for the solution. It seems to work partially. I still have some cells left which I am not able to reach after scrolling. Is there any work-around?

Answer (score 0):

In the method below , return the number of rows more than those you are seeing in the device/simulator:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  // return 12;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must declare the attribute delegate of the table like self:

`self.miTableView.delegate = self`

You can do it in viewDidLoad function.

Don't forget extend to UITableViewDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of the above worked for me. Finally I simply add

```
self.miTableView.reloadData()
```

to the ViewDidLoad() ... and everything works.

Maybe it's because I use

```
 self.miTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

maybe a reload after this is necessary ... hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

in my case the SuperView is User Interaction Enabled not selected
make sure the User Interaction Enabled Checkmark For SuperView

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the class is created programmatically and there is no xib, you can address the scrolling problem directly by adding to viewWillAppear (not viewDidLoad) in ObjectiveC:

```
`self.tableView.scrollEnabled=YES;`
```